# JavaScript crashes randomly in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I have a JS code, which more specifically deals with the generation of jQuery UI Dialogs, included in my pages as external file as `<script src="js/dialogs.js"></script>`. In one of these pages sits a Dojo DataGrig, which works very well without including `dialogs.js`, but does not startup if I do include it.

This is my JS code:

```
function loadDialog(dialogObj, title, url, params, resizable, modal, draggable, closeOnEscape) {
            // customizes the dialog options
            dialogObj.dialog("option", "width", "auto");
            dialogObj.dialog("option", "height", "auto");
            dialogObj.dialog("option", "title", title);
            dialogObj.dialog("option", "resizable", resizable);
            dialogObj.dialog("option", "modal", modal);
            dialogObj.dialog("option", "draggable", draggable);
            dialogObj.dialog("option", "closeOnEscape", closeOnEscape);
            dialogObj.dialog("option", "position", {my: "center center", at: "center center", of: window, collision: "none"});
            $.get(url, params, function(data) {
                    dialogObj.html(data);
                    dialogObj.dialog("open");
            });
    }

    // 'dialogObj' is the jQuery selector of the div onto which
    // the dialog must be loaded, while 'type' is just an integer which
    // defines which activity is to be created, nothing interesting anyway
    function createActivity(dialogObj, type) {
            var type = type || 0;
            var params = {"type":type};
            loadDialog(dialogObj, "Create New Activity", "createActivity.php", params, true, true, true, true);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#dialog").empty();
            $("#dialog").load("createActivity.php").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    closeText: "Close",
                    show: "blind",
                    hide: "fade",
                    open: function() {
                            $('input[type="date"]').each(function() {
                                    if ($(this).length > 0) {
                                            $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
                                    }
                            });
                    },
                    close: function() {
                            $('#startingDate').datepicker('hide');
                            $('#endingDate').datepicker('hide');
                    }
            });
    });
```

The function `createActivity` is called `onclick` onto a bunch of buttons in some of my pages.

This happens in FireFox but NOT in Chrome, because the latter tries to correct every error it can, while FF prefers to crash directly. Does anyone notice any conceptual or coding error there? Do you notice any point which could lead to Memory Leak or Memory Corruption in FF?
By the way, of course my console shows no warnings nor errors for me.

Alternatively, I am combining this code with some Modernizr snippets in order to detect wether some features are enabled or not in the client's browser. Is anyone of you guys aware of a known issue with the combination jQuery - Dojo Toolkit - Modernizr?

Comment: "This happens in FireFox but NOT in Chrome, because the latter tries to correct every error it can, while FF prefers to crash directly" - where did you hear that? Doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: I knew that Chrome, when it finds problems with syntax or memory which it can understand, males an attempt to "tamper" the problem. However, the situation is kind of weird, correction or not xD doesn't chrome try to do that? I faced some situations in which errors in FF became warnings in Chrome, so I was guessing so, I didn't investigate so much the differences between the two browsers yet!

Comment: My experience with Firefox is when you're developing a heavy client-side Javascript application and constantly refresh the page with the inspector open, after a couple of days of doing so it eventually crashes due to insufficient memory. It's not something you generally have to worry about for user consumption of your app, because they're not accessing it in the same way a developer would.

Comment: LoL, really. I am surprised this persists throughout many poweroffs and powerons, if this is the problem xD in effect it happens only in FF. Thanks for pointing that out to me :) the app I'm working on is really heavily relying on JS!